# Why module style is overlap when same filename

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, styles

I'm try to style for each component separately by using css-loader plugin of Webpack. But when files has the same name (for example: 'index.scss') and has the same property (for example: '.container') it will combine both style, but in this case I just need ones. How can I solve that

This is my Webpack configuration:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
            { 
                loader: 'style-loader',
                options: {
                    insertAt: 'top',
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            },
            {
                // Handle import/ require css
                // It help to css for each component
                // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope
                loader: 'css-loader', 
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true ,
                    localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
                    camelCase: true,

                } 
            },
            { 
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    // minimize: true,
                    plugins: () => [
                        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                        // Help to generate specific css for each component
                        // require('postcss-modules'),
                        autoprefixer({
                            browsers: [
                            '>1%',
                            'last 4 versions',
                            'Firefox ESR',
                            'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                            ],
                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                        }),
                    ],  
                }
            },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
        ],
    },
]
```

Example:
`src/screen1/index.tsx`

```
const styles = require('./index.scss')

const Dashboard = ({ children, url }: IDashboardPropsIn) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.body}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And I has 2 files: `src/screen2/index.scss` and `src/screen1/index.scss`
Somehow in class which name `body--[hash:64]` has both styles from 2 files

`src/screen1/index.scss`

```
:local {
  .body {
    grid-area: body;
    background-color: $white;
 }
}
```

and `src/screen2/index.scss`

```
:local {
  .body {
    display: flex;
 }
}
```

Style of `body--[hash:64]` will be

```
grid-area: body;
background-color: $white;
display: flex;
```

But in this case I only one import the file `src/screen1/index.scss` such as

```
grid-area: body;
background-color: $white;
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the `modules` option in your config

```
        {
            // Handle import/ require css
            // It help to css for each component
            // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope
            loader: 'css-loader', 
            options: {
                sourceMap: true ,
                localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
                camelCase: true,
                modules: true, // or 'local' | 'global' | false

            } 
        },
```

Read more in the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules)

Comment: I tried 'global', 'local', true but still doesn't work (refreshed webpack when updating)

Comment: try `modules: true` in the config. And remove `:local` from your styles you don't need it.

Comment: Still not work. 2 styles file with different path but when compile that will same name such as `index__body--WMbpV`

Comment: I solved this problems by update the new version `css-loader` from 0.28.7 to 0.28.11

Answer (score 0):

Update `css-loader` package to 0.28.11 version